# How do I delete only files not sub-folder from parent directory in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark, sh, databricks, azure-databricks

`%fs rm -r /my/directory/path/partner_code=xyz/`

If I use above command then all files and sub folders will get deleted from my parent directory. But I want to delete only files (not the sub-folders and anything inside from that sub-directory) which are present in my parent directory.

`%fs rm -f /my/directory/path/partner_code=xyz/`

If I use above command to do so then I am getting following error:

> error: not found: value overwrite

How do I do this correctly?